# glassfish .jsp 404 not found

Tags: java, jsp, glassfish

When I try to redirect to .jsp file I get 404 error, like server can't see it. Please, help to solve this problem.

My redirection:

```
    Tour tour = new Tour();
    tour.setCountryTo(request.getParameter("countryTo"));
    tour.setAmountOfDays(request.getParameter("amountOfDays"));
    session.setAttribute("tour", tour);
    response.sendRedirect("final.jsp");
```

[image: photo is here]

Comment: Where is your jsp file ? Show the file structure of this project. _like server can't see it_ can't reach it most likely. (edit the question with those information)

Comment: you can see file structure on the photo, I don't know how to add it correctly

Comment: And where is the code you show ? Sorry, I missed it. Here I have edit it (just need a `!` in front of the line ;) )

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but i thing this will word:

```
response.sendRedirect("/final.jsp");
```